# Repositories in .net core library

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I'm trying to wrap basic actions fro model(like get by id, etc.) in repositories. However I'm facing with two problems:

**1. Connection String** : Is there any solution to put it in config, and not to hard code it in class, like I did?

```
 public const string ConnectionString = "Server = (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=pinchdb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";// can I get rid of it?
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProjectDepartments> ProjectsDepartments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Roles> Roles { get; set; }
    public effMercContext(DbContextOptions<effMercContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectDepartments>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.ProjectId, t.DepartmentId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectDepartments>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Project)
            .WithMany(p => p.ProjectDepartment)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.ProjectId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectDepartments>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Department)
            .WithMany(t => t.ProjectDepartment)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.DepartmentId);
    }
}
public class EffMercDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<effMercContext>
{
    public effMercContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<effMercContext>();
        builder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=pinchdb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
        return new effMercContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

**2. Can I call Dbcontext without options to implement methods?**

```
      public Employee GetByID(int id)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<effMercContext>();// how can I get rid of this and just call effMercContext
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(effMercContext.ConnectionString);
        using (effMercContext db = new effMercContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
        {
            return db.Employees.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can put your connectionstring in `appsettings.json` as shown below.
   [image]
   Also, you can have `config transforms` for the `appsettings.json` based on the environments.

   in the Startup.cs

   [image]

   Access the above config while creating the DbContext.

   ```
         services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
           options =>
               options.UseSqlServer(
                   configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"], b =>
                           b.MigrationsAssembly("MyProj.Web"))
   ```

   2. Add a default constructor to `effMercContext`. Then you shouldn't need to pass `DbContextOptions`.

Comment: If I add default constructor, will I get access to my models and Dbsets?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to.

Comment: Also, you could use your `EffMercDbContextFactory ` instead of directly accessing `effMercContext`.